# Node.js split file lines

Tags: node.js

I want to write a script that divides the lines read from the file into packages of 25, unfortunately the sample package returns 40 codes. I would like to do so that, for example, he divided me into packages of 25 items. I mean, I have, for example, 60 codes, this creates 2 packages of 25, and one with 10 codes. Unfortunately, I can't handle it.

```
const fs = require('fs');
fs.readFile('code.txt', function (err, data) {
    if (err) throw err;
    const array = data.toString().split("\n");
    let count = 0;

    let items = [];
    for (let i in array) {
        items.push({
            PutRequest: {
                Item: {
                    code: array[i]
                }
            }
        });

        let params = {
            RequestItems: {
                'TABLE_NAME': items
            }
        };

        if (count === 25) {
            dynamoDB.batchWrite(params, function (err, data) {
                if (err) {
                    console.log(err);
                } else {
                    count = 0;
                    items = [];
                }
            });

        }else{
            count++;
        }
    }
});
```

code.txt content

> https://0bin.net/paste/NA8-4hkq#1Ohwt5uUkQqE0YscwnxTX2gxEqlvAUVKp1JRipBCsZg

Any idea what I do wrong?

Comment: Is the contents of `code.txt` sensitive? If not can you share it please? Would make it easier to test a solution.

Comment: @Isolated Done :) I added link to code.txt

Comment: Your `dynamoDB.batchWrite()` is asynchronous. Thus its callback is executed only after the loop has completed. So `items` and `count` are never reset ...  Any possiblility you could switch to a `async/await` based approach (ie Promises)? That would make things a lot easier.

Comment: @derpirscher Generally, I have to batch add 100k records to DynamoDB, if I do it, I have to think up myself: D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your dynamoDB.batchWrite() is asynchronous. Thus its callback is executed only after the loop has completed. So items and count are never reset ...

The easiest would be, if you could switch to an promise based approach like the following

```
const BATCHSIZE = 25;
const fs = require('fs').promises;

async function batchLoad() {
   const lines = (await fs.readFile("code.txt", "utf-8")).split("\n");
   while (lines.length > 0) {
      const items = lines.splice(0, BATCHSIZE).map(l => ({PutRequest: {Item: { code: l }}}));
      const params = { RequestItems: { TABLE_NAME: items}};

      await new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        dynamoDb.batchWrite(params, (err) => {
          if (err) return reject(err);
          resolve();
        });
      });
   }

}
```

A callback based approach could look like this

```
const BATCHSIZE = 25;

fs.readFile("code.txt", "utf-8", (err, data) => {
  const lines = data.split("\n");

  function writeBatch() {
    if (!lines.length) return;
    const items = lines.splice(0, BATCHSIZE).map(l => ({PutRequest: {Item: { code: l }}}));
    const params = { RequestItems: { TABLE_NAME: items}};

    dynamoDb.batchWrite(params, err => {
      if (err) ...
      else writeBatch();
    });
  }

  writeBatch();
}
```

The function `writeBatch` takes a certain number of lines from your original array and writes them into the database. Only afer the write into the DB was successful, it recursively calls itself and handles the next batch. But be aware, that this approach may exceed the maximum call stack size and throw an error.

You can also make either of this approaches not manipulate the lines array (which may be quite expensive), but just get out the current slice

```
const BATCHSIZE = 25;
const fs = require('fs').promises;

async function batchLoad() {
   const lines = (await fs.readFile("code.txt", "utf-8")).split("\n");
   let currentIndex = 0;
   while (currentIndex < lines.length) {
      const items = lines.slice(currentIndex, currentIndex + BATCHSIZE).map(l => ({PutRequest: {Item: { code: l }}}));
      const params = { RequestItems: { TABLE_NAME: items}};

      await new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        dynamoDb.batchWrite(params, (err) => {
          if (err) return reject(err);
          resolve();
        });
      });
      currentIndex += BATCHSIZE;
   }

}
```

and

```
const BATCHSIZE = 25;

fs.readFile("code.txt", "utf-8", (err, data) => {
  const lines = data.split("\n");
  function writeBatch(currentIndex) {
    if (currentIndex >= lines.length) return;
    const items = lines.slice(currentIndex, currentIndex + BATCHSIZE).map(l => ({PutRequest: {Item: { code: l }}}));
    const params = { RequestItems: { TABLE_NAME: items}};

    dynamoDb.batchWrite(params, err => {
      if (err) ...
      else writeBatch(currentIndex + BATCHSIZE);
    });
  }

  writeBatch(0);
}
```

To prevent stumbling into a maximum callstack exception you may also add the next batch to the eventloop and not call it recursively. Ie

```
dynamoDb.batchWrite(params, err => {
      if (err) ...
      else setTimeout(()=> { writeBatch(currentIndex + BATCHSIZE);}, 0);
    });
```

This way you won't build up a massive callstack from recursive calls.

To keep track of how many records are already saved to the db you could simply store the current counter in a file. When you restart the process, load that file and check how many lines to skip. Don't forget to remove the file, once all records have been saved ... For example with the first approach:

```
const BATCHSIZE = 25;
const fs = require('fs').promises;

async function batchLoad() {
   const lines = (await fs.readFile("code.txt", "utf-8")).split("\n");
   const skipLines = 0;
   try {
     skipLines = +(await fs.readFile("skip.txt", "utf-8"));
     if (isNaN(skipLines)) skipLines = 0;
     lines.splice(0, skipLines);
   } catch (e) {
     skipLines = 0;
   }
   while (lines.length > 0) {
      const items = lines.splice(0, BATCHSIZE).map(l => ({PutRequest: {Item: { code: l }}}));
      const params = { RequestItems: { TABLE_NAME: items}};

      await new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        dynamoDb.batchWrite(params, (err) => {
          if (err) return reject(err);
          resolve();
        });
      });
      skipLines += BATCHSIZE;
      await fs.writeFile("skip.txt", `${skipLines}`);
   }

   try {
     await fs.unlink("skip.txt");
   } catch (e) {
   }
}
```

Comment: 33 lines to 18, async/await is so much better! Just one note, below resolve should be `});`, tried to edit but needed to be 6 characters

Comment: Well, TBH I stripped out some errorhandling :-)  And thanks for the hint about the missing `)`.

Comment: Let's just leave this one and then there's no option but to adjust to this. If I could upvote this again I would.

Comment: @derpirscher Your first solution works great, but you have mistake: ```await fs.readFile("code.txt", "utf-8") ``` . readFile as second argument need callback, I changed readFile to readFileSync.

This is now a question, what, for example, I have 30 million records to import and the script will stop working at some point, how to do it to resume from the last saved code.

Comment: No. It doesn't need a callback because it's the promise version of readFile https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html (note the updated `require()`). Why do you think this will "stop working at some point"? You may not be able to read all 30 Mio lines at once with readFile and could switch to a streaming based approach. But other than that? You may need to keep track of how many batches you already handled and store this value somewhere, maybe in an other file or in the DB?

Comment: @derpirscher I tested your solution and, for example, the first time I read 1000 codes without a problem, and for example, the second time I was interrupted at 600 due to some DynamoDB error. And now I would like to add a solution so that in case of an error it will resume from the last saved line, unfortunately I have no idea how to do it, because I am not very good with js,

Comment: @derpirscher I don't know why, but the script after 160k records added crashes without any error.

Comment: @PawelC It's quite hard to believe there is NO error at all. Are you catching errors which are thrown by calling batchload. For instance `batchLoad().catch(e => console.log(e))` Any unhandled promise rejections?